# Throwing errors in async await functions and catching from where it's called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

How can we catch error from an async await function from where it's called?

For example, I have a React component which calls a async-await function imported from another module. When I use `Promise.reject("An unknown has occurred");` in that function, so in my React component why can't I get the error in `asyncAwaitFunction.catch((e)=>console.log(e))`?

I even tried `throw "An unknown occured"`, but it doesn't seem to work.

**react component**

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    add(formData, code)
      .then(() => router.push("/dashboard/manage"))
      .catch((e) => setError(e)); //I want error to be catched here
  };
```

**functions.js**

```js
export const addUser = async (details, code) => {

 const isExist = await isUser(code);

 if (!isExist) {

  const add = db.batch();    //firebase batch write

  add.set(userID(code), details);    //Add details to databse

  add.commit()
   .catch((e)=> {
   console.log(e);    // error occurs confirmed
   Promise.reject("Unknown error occurred"); //this does't get catched in component.
  });
    
 } else {
   Promise.reject("Already Exists!"); 
 }
};
```

Comment: `await add.commit();`

Comment: `this works` ... doubt it. You want to return or throw that rejected Promise (or directly throw an error)

Comment: i might be wrong about that line, earlier i used `throw` that used to work. not sure about `Promise.reject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rejected Promise (either from a Promise that you constructed that rejected, or from a `Promise.reject`) will only be caught if:

- a `.catch` is added onto the end of that Promise expression, or
- that Promise expression is returned inside an async function or a `.then`, and the caller of the async function or after the `.then` callback, there's a `.catch`

So, you should change to something like:

```
export const addUser = async (details, code) => {
   const isExist = await isUser(code);
   if (isExist) {
      return Promise.reject('Already Exists!');
   }

   const add = db.batch();    //firebase batch write
   add.set(userID(code), details);    //Add details to databse
   return add.commit().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);    // error occurs confirmed
      return Promise.reject("Unknown error occurred");
   });
};
```

But do you really need to log in the `.commit().catch`? If not, it'd be cleaner to just return the `commit` Promise and catch in the caller:

```
export const addUser = async (details, code) => {
   const isExist = await isUser(code);
   if (isExist) {
      return Promise.reject('Already Exists!');
   }

   const add = db.batch();    //firebase batch write
   add.set(userID(code), details);    //Add details to databse
   return add.commit();
};
```

A Promise that is `await`ed or returned from an async function will have its errors (or its resolve value) percolate up to the caller of the async function.

Comment: If I could add more votes to this, it'll be a million more.

Comment: Perfect! Also thanks for the cleaner `if` statement suggestion. BTW I would still return `commit.catch((e)=>Promise.reject("Unknown error occurrect"))` as I don't want to catch the entire error object in my component, so instead I will use it for custom message, just to show that some error has occurred, and no more information.